# Downloads images from firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide, firebase-storage

I am developing an app, using firebase, which reads images from firebase storage into listview using glide.
Do you know what's the best way to download images into listview items?

Comment: In our [Zero to App talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE) at Google I/O we used exactly that setup in the Android app. Have a look at the [code for that app](https://gist.github.com/puf/f49a1b07e92952b44f2dc36d9af04e3c) to get started.

Comment: Thanks. But what I mean is that in my app I want to show photos that come with the app, which already in the firebase storage, not photos uploaded by users. Do  you know what ' s the best pratice to read from storage in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using glide you can use it to fill ImageView in ListView. Glide has method `into`

e.g.

```
  final ImageView myImageView;

  Glide
    .with(myFragment)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .crossFade()
    .into(myImageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not acquainted with Firebase Storage, but I suppose that when you upload a image into this platform, they give you an URL in order to access to this resource. Well, if this is correct, try this code in your adapter class for the ListView:

```
ImageView img = (ImagenView)findViewbyid(R.id.myimageview);
String url = "http://..."; //Firebase URL to the picture

Glide.with(yourActivity).load(url).into(img);
```

Do not forget to modify your gradle file with Glide path.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Version `0.6.0` of the [FirebaseUI-Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/storage/README.md) library includes the ability to take a Firebase `StorageReference` and load an image using Glide:

```
// Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
StorageReference storageReference = ...;

// ImageView in your Activity
ImageView imageView = ...;

// Load the image using Glide
Glide.with(this /* context */)
        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(imageView);
```

To include it, just add `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'` to your `build.gradle`.

Comment: How do I get the image from Firebase at a specific size?

Comment: We don't have support for this right now in FirebaseUI, you'll need to upload  resized images yourself.  One great way to do this is using Cloud Functions for Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

• Try to add **app-level** Dependency

```
dependencies { 
// FirebaseUI Storage only 
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0' 
}
```

• Use the next code to get the image from firebase storage

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view); 
Glide.with(context) 
               .using(new FirebaseImageLoader()) 
               .load(pathReference ) 
               .into(imageView);
```